# Client application and secure data exchange without ssl/tls

Tags: security, encryption, client-server

I have my own home server and port 80/443 is blocked from my ISP provider.  I want to create a Qt gui application that saves my data on my server using REST (using port 8080 or something) using nginx/node.  The user would log in using a username/password.  What would be another alternative to secure the data being exchanged?  Or a good solution for encrypting the data back and forth between the client and the server?

Comment: Is this a misunderstanding about SSL? You can use SSL on almost any port. (It doesn't have to be 443). http://superuser.com/questions/791218/can-i-use-another-port-other-than-443-for-ssl-communication

Comment: Your right I was thinking port 443 only but its just a port that can be used instead.  Thanks